# Mysql Foreign key limitation - Does this system fit my needs?

Tags: mysql, database

I have some question about how Mysql handle foreign key, and if I should configure my Database like this or not.

In my application, I have multiple **Owners**. Each owners can have access to multiple **domains**. Each domains have a list of **Users** that can reach hundred to thousands entries.
Also, each domains have also access to multiples **Modules** (up to 10/20), and each modules have some configuration in it.

So if I have 1000 Owners, with 10 domains each, with 1000 users each, I end up with 10.000.000 users in a single table, is this a bad thing ?

Does Mysql foreign key system is my best bet ? Should I try something else or avoid some traps ? Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: that depends on what hardware you have, and how good your indexes are. And then when the need arises you can look into partitioning.

Comment: A foreign key is just a reference some tables primary key. The user table should not duplicate users. A user can have multiple domains? Create a new table that keeps track of user domains.

Comment: The thing is, I want to duplicate users. If you are in 2 domains, you will have two separate stats in both domains. Edit - What I can do is a "Stats" table with a link to a User and a domain ?

Comment: No you just need to create a stats table with a domain foreign key.

Comment: "Does this system fit my needs?" - Which system?

Comment: partitioning also isn't the silver bullet performance wise @nbk there are cases where you go wrong with it as only RANGE and LIST as Partitioning Types are useful, the others like HASH will not scale very good..   Only problem there is a limit around 1000 partitions  .

Comment: Why not? If the stats table is linked to the Domain table only, how do I find wich entry of the Stat table goes with wich user?

Comment: O partition limit [not around 1000](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html#partitioning-limitations-max-partitions) anymore.. Prior to MySQL 5.6.7, the maximum possible number of partitions for a given table not using the NDB storage engine was **1024**. Beginning with MySQL 5.6.7, this limit is increased to **8192** partitions...

Comment: *"So if I have 1000 Owners, with 10 domains each, with 1000 users each, I end up with 10.000.000 users in a single table, is this a bad thing ?"*  Assumming your server machine has modern hardware.. And the MySQL server is correcty configured for InnoDB usage and correct designed datatypes in the tables, correctly written queries and indexes for those queries.. This number (10.000.000) of records should be like "nothing" for a modern MySQL version to handle...

Comment: To me it seems that you do not know to model many-to-many relationships in a relational database. Not by duplicating records, but by using junction tables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that one domain has only one owner the schema shown in this image take care of the requirements. You can have the stats of an user for a particular domain in the DomainUsers table.

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbd6db